# Grouping of groups by each user, Java, Ubuntu

Tags: arraylist, split

I have mutilple list of line, for example:

```
root : root
user : user adm cdrom sudo dip
```

I want it to look like this.

```
root : root
user : user
user : adm
user : cdrom
user : sudo
user : dip
```

Thankyou In Advance

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm sorry for my vague question. I am trying to extract the roles into its user. This is the out ub : ub adm cdrom. I want it to become ub : ub, ub : adm, ub : cdrom.

Comment: Create [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), describe your issues, it's not even clear where do you have that list - is this some txt file?

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved f.ex. with a simple Perl one-liner:

```
$ cat dummy.txt 
root : root
user : user adm cdrom sudo dip

$ perl <dummy.txt -lane 'print "$F[0] : $_" for (@F[2..$#F])'
root : root
user : user
user : adm
user : cdrom
user : sudo
user : dip
```

---

**BONUS CODE:** dissection of the Perl one-liner:

```perl
$ perl -MO=Deparse -lane 'print "$F[0] : $_" for (@F[2..$#F])'
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    chomp $_;
    our @F = split(' ', $_, 0);
    print "$F[0] : $_" foreach (@F[2 .. $#F]);
}
```